# How to fetch payment and transfer details against a settlement?

Tags: razorpay

I am using https://api.razorpay.com/v1/settlements to fetch all the settlements but now I need to fetch transfer and payment details against the settlements.

Comment: And the problem you face is?

Comment: I am looking for an api that returns payment details against a settlement id